IPv6 firewall rule(s) to allow public access to different webservers (80, 443)
I've set up two webservers witch are running next to each other (2 different computers).
I like to have public access trough port 80 and port 443 trough the IPv6 protocol.
Am using an Unifi Security Gateway.
For IPv4:

port 80 and port 443 are forwarded to the server1 ip address.
for server2 this is a problem as I cannot forward the same ports to a different ip address...

For IPv6 (the willing solution as there is no NAT):

I created two AAAA records (on two subdomains) one for each server with points directly to the (global) IPv6 addresses of both servers.
I created an "Address Group" containing the two (global) IPv6 addresses of server1 and server2
I created a "Port Group" of the http and https ports: (80, 443)

From within my LAN everything works fine on IPv6 for both servers.
On IPv4 only the (forwarded) server1 works, which is expected.
When I do a test from the Internet (IPv6) I cannot get trough to neither of the webservers, only the IPv4 fallback works fine for server1 (also as expected).
Here is the response from the letsdebug.net test:
AAAA Not Working Error:

www.website.com has an AAAA (IPv6) record (2a02:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:dc69) but a test request to this address over port 80 did not succeed. 
Your web server must have at least one working IPv4 or IPv6 address. 
You should either ensure that validation requests to this domain succeed over IPv6, or remove its AAAA record.

A timeout was experienced while communicating with www.website.com

Here is a screenshot from my USG Firewall Settings:

What can I do to make my two webservers reachable from outside (at least trough IPv6), but only allow the traffic needed without opening unnecessary security holes? I cannot find a lot of Unifi documentation for IPv6 but I guess the IPv6 Firewall settings should be comparable to other gateways? I'm very new to IPv6 but now I must use it, from inside it is working perfectly.
Thanks in advance.

Do not specify a source port in your rules. For incoming packets to a server, only the destination port identifies the service, while the source port is always chosen randomly by the client (and in IPv4 can also be further randomized by the client's SNAT).
(The use of two port numbers, one on each end, is what allows TCP to distinguish between concurrent connections from the same client to the same server – even if both connections are made to port 80, they come from unique source ports.)


but I guess the IPv6 Firewall settings should be comparable to other gateways?

On that note – I've seen some gateways use the terms 'source' and 'destination' in the context of IPv4 DNAT (port forwarding) to mean the external and internal port numbers, but that's flatly wrong; even "port forwarding" rules deal with the destination port only. (Better labels would be 'old/original/external' vs 'new/internal'.)

This actually did the trick! Thanks a million, I did not know that. Let's debug says now: "All OK!". BUT: The strange thing is... The first time I connect to the url from outside, it is not getting the certificate with ipv6, after I port-forward ipv4 to server2 temporarily, it gets the certificate. Then I can forward the ports back back to server1 (ipv4) and the connection to server2 keeps working with IPv6. Just to catch the certificate the first time I get the error: "This web site requires a secure connection". Any idea what it could be? I would maybe open another port for that?

Does your server see that initial connection (does it show up in log files or tcpdump)?

good question, I'm trying to figure out the tcpdump filter parameters for ipv6 because now it is a storm on information that's being dumped. It seems like when I refresh from outside a lot of traffic (I don't understand) is passing... But I still cannot access the website from outside with ipv6. The letsdebug site says this: acme: error code 403 "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized": 2a02:a03f:ea7a:9d13:f66b:8cff:fe90:ae41: Invalid response from https://acloud.acawa.be/.well-known/acme-challenge/j-mZhpU1hpuw5AlxsVHx9qgQS8qVG2lhVUrIf3-wi-E: 404.

Start with not port 22 to exclude traffic of the SSH connection you're using to perform the dump... or narrow it down to port 80 or 443 for HTTP(S). Generally the web server itself should log the requests too.

Did some decent testing before I answered... Not on tcpdump neither in the apache-ssl log I can find any sign from that that "initial connection" when I am outside of my LAN. Since I added the Unifi Firewall rule allow on tcp Any to ipv6-address on ports 80 and 443 (I even try it once from Any to Any), nothing is coming in from outside... Then I went to my ISP router settings and set the Firewall setting to low: "All connection attempts coming from the WAN or initiated from the LAN are permitted." So how can I initiate the connection from the LAN trough ipv6? (with ipv4 it works).
